# moderation in code for binomial coefficient

Tags: c++

I recently saw the code for binomial coefficient in time and space efficient way.

```
ll C(ll n,ll k)
{
    ll p=1;

    if(k>n-k)
    k=n-k;

    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
    p*=(n-i);
    p/=(i+1);
    }

return p;
}
```

Lets consider below three different ways of doing this.

**case 1:**

```
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
{
p*=(n-i);
p/=(i+1);
}
```

**case 2:**

```
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
{
p*=(n-i)/(i+1);
}
```

**case 3:**

```
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
p*=(n-i);

for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
p/=(n-i);
```

In both case 1 and case 3 answer is coming right and in case 2, it is coming different. 
But only case 3 should yield the correct answer, neither 2 and 1 as in both of the cases the fraction part would get removed due to division just after multiplication.

Can anybody explain me this stuff.

Comment: What's `ll`? Is that shorthand for `long long`?

Comment: Be more careful with your types – signed overflow is undefined.

Comment: Your case 3 looks very strange. Are you sure that it produces the correct answer?

Comment: @molbdnilo, sorry , in second statement of case 3, it is division not multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're dealing with integer arithmetic, evaluation order matters.

Rewriting your cases slightly, you have

1: multiply first

```
p = (p * (n-i)) / (i+1)
```

and 2: divide first

```
p = p * ((n-i) / (i+1))
```

If `n-i` is smaller than `i+1`, `(n-i)/(i+1)` is zero.
Thus, your case 2 will result in zero, and case 1 won't.

For instance, if you have

```
 int x = 2;
```

then `x *= 3/4;` results in `x` being 0, but after `x *= 3; x /= 4;` it would be 1.

Your case 3 must be a typo, but it's also a case of "multiply first".

Answer (score 2):

**Consider Case 1:**

```
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
{
  p*=(n-i); //statement 1
  p/=(i+1); //statement 2
}
```

In the first iteration, it will be an integer division with no truncation as `i` is 1. 
In the second iteration, in statement 1, `p` will be a product of an odd number and an even number (as they are consecutive) and so will be divisible by 2 in statement 2.

In the third iteration, in statement 1, `p` will be a product of an three consecutive numbers in descending order and so will be divisible by 3 in statement 2.

And so on...

**Consider Case 2:**
This fails because integer division is performed first in the rhs of the statement

```
p*=(n-i)/(i+1);
```

This leads to truncation and you have correctly surmised this.

**Consider Case 3:**
I believe your code should be this:

```
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
p*=(n-i);

for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
p/=(i+1);
```

Here we see something similar to what happened in case 1 but it is quite obvious.
You multiply consecutive integers first in decreasing order (upto k) first and **after** that
divide that by the product of integers in increasing order (upto k). This is the formula for binomial coefficient and gives the correct result.

**Note:** Since **Case 3** has consecutive multiplications before division starts, there might be overflow. So **Case 1** is to be preferred.

Comment: Note: Case 1 should be preferred, to limit overflows

Comment: @Damien: Updated with a note. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I got the logic.